# Exaggerated view count in question list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958090/send-group-imessage-using-applescript), on Stack Overflow’s list of questions, appears to have approximately 2,000 views:

[image: 2k views]

However, upon opening said question, the actual, exact view count turned out just a tad… lower:

[image: 1,525 views]

That’s 475 made-up views! I'd be fine with, say 1,750 rounding to 2,000, but I think 1,525 is a bit much. Perhaps have it display as "1.5k views" instead? Or, at the very least, simply avoid rounding up to the next thousand until the number is only, say, 249 views away, rather than (presumably) 499.

Comment: This is correct rounding for integer k value, so calling it a bug seems a bit harsh. This is basically then a feature request for higher resolution view counts to an arbitrary number of decimals.

Comment: I can understand that this is correct rounding if we're enforcing an integer view count, so, yes, I guess it's technically a feature request. However, I called it a bug because 475 (presumably up to 499) is a pretty high possible number of displayed views that aren't really there. The most minimal possible change, I suppose, would be to simply avoid rounding _up_ until we're only, say, 250 away from the next thousand.

Comment: But 250 seems like a very arbitrary choice, doesn't it? Other people may feel that 100 would be more correct? Some might say not to round up at all?

Comment: So what counts should be displayed when the view count is 749 and 199749? Also, how does the difference of view count affect your action towards the question?

Comment: @NisargShah Questions with more views have attracted more people's attention, and therefore may be of interest to me as a reader. That doesn't mean I _don't_ read questions with a comparatively low view count; it depends on the situation. Somewhat similar to how certain social media sites display view count right in-line with the content link: to represent others' engagement in the content (of course, if the engagement is largely negative, a low/negative vote count will show that quite nicely).

Answer (score 15):

OK, let's say we do things as you want. When rounding to 1 significant digit, you round up when you're 25% from the next number and down otherwise. That means if the number is 1,749, then the user sees 1K.

How exactly is that *better*? All you've done is trade one erroneous number for another. Indeed, you've made it *more* erroneous in an absolute sense, because 1,749 is almost 75% larger than 1,000. And yet, the user still just sees 1K.

By using real rounding, you ensure that the error between the number you see and the actual number is never greater than 50% in either direction.

Comment: Okay, I can see that. Fair logic. I guess I was simply put off by the amount of rounding being done with the "K" numbers, but so many websites use that style of number display now that I suppose I'm outnumbered.

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy: Personally, I think that numbers should never be rounded to less than 2 digits of precision like this. Especially in a UI element that can clearly handle another digit. So to me, it's not whether it should be 1K or 2K, but whether it should be 2K or 1.5K.

Comment: That's a good idea, and also the solution I had in mind first, but that I figured would've required more work on the devs' part. I don't think this question is salvageable as a feature request like this, but I'll make a new one in the morning; do you remember seeing any similar requests on here in the past?

Answer (score 11):

You can simply hover over the view count to see the actual views.

For example, here's one of the questions that shows '1k views' in the Questions view. As you hover the mouse over the '1k' text, you get the actual view count as a tooltip.

[image]

Here's the picture of question page, to confirm the number:

[image]

Comment: Isn't quite the same as a more accurate count on first glance, but useful tip nevertheless; thanks.