# Tooltip missing in new layout

Tags: bug

Is [this feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360181/7920473) not implemented in new layout?

[image]

When I hover on the "5k views" nothing shows up in tooltip. Can this be a bug to be worked on?

[image]

Comment: This should be reported here: [New responsive Activity page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/289905).